# in Python, I'm trying to import a separate module file within a value-returning function but keep getting an error, any ideas?

Tags: python, function, import, module, return-value

I am trying to import the following module into the below code but I keep getting

```
    comput()
TypeError: comput() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'r' and 'h'
```

I have tried some varying solutions and watched some videos but I can't figure this one out, any ideas?

---

```
def comput(r, h):
    if h <= 40:
        p = r * h
    else:
        p = r * 40 + (r * 1.5 * ( h - 40))
    return p


comput()
```

---

```
import program5_1_module


def main():
    pay()
    pay()
    pay()

def pay():

    name = input('Enter employee name: ')
    rate = float(input(f'Enter hourly rate for {name}: '))
    hours = float(input(f'Enter hours for {name} this week: '))

    pay = comput(rate, hours)
    print(f'Pay for {name} is ${pay:,.2f}')


main()
```

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with imports or return values. You have a function with 2 parameters but are calling it with 0 arguments.

Comment: you need to include the 2 parameters, for example `comput(5, 40)`

Answer (score 1):

Python executes all module-level code when importing another code.

In your first code, `comput()` raises `TypeError` because you are calling function with 2 parameters but you gave no argument.

In your second code, you import `program5_1_module`(I think this is name of your first code?), and python executes all code in `program5_1_module`, which includes `comput()`

Solution:

- Remove `comput()` (9th line of your first code, because it makes error)
- If you want to test calling `comput()` in first code then wrap it using `if __name__ == "__main__"`, like `if __name__ == "__main__": comput(a, b)`.

  - `if __name__ == "__main__"` informs python interpreter that this should not be executed when importing